# Stylesheet import error while creating a new Spartacus 6.1 storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am able to successfully install a Spartacus 6.1 storefront but while building, I am getting below error,

I checked the ccss file for any reference error, but it was able to navigate.

```
./src/styles/spartacus/asm.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "..\..\styles-config";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles\spartacus\asm.scss 1:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles/spartacus/cart.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "..\..\styles-config";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles\spartacus\cart.scss 1:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles/spartacus/checkout.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "..\..\styles-config";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles\spartacus\checkout.scss 1:9  root stylesheet




error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the exact same error while setting up a Spartacus 6.0 store. I was able to solve this by replacing the backward slashes with forward slashes in the import statement of `styles-config` in the `.scss` files.

Changed the below line in the `.scss` files

```
@import "..\\..\styles-config";
```

as

```
@import "../../styles-config";
```